# How can I extract peak values from auto-correlated data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, correlation

I have information (20,000 frames of data) about an audio track that I have auto-correlated using:

```
[r,lags] = xcorr(XX,XX,'biased');
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Which hopefully is so far so good. Ideally I would like to be able to take the frame number that corresponds to the highest part of the second peak. I've read around and tried a load of different methods but I just can't seem to get it to retrieve the information for me.

Would anybody be able to shed some light on what I have to do?

Many thanks!

---

**edit1:**
I have tried using `findpeaks`, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not sure if that's because I'm using the wrong data or not.

**edit2:** I'm currently testing a method to use on just this audio track, but soon I want to expand it so that I can perform this method on a whole directory of files, so I kind of need a script that can detect peaks rather than finding the information myself.

**edit3:** My .M file:

```
[y, fs, nb] = wavread('Three.wav');                 %# Load the signal into variable y

frameWidth = 441;                                   %# 10ms
numSamples = length(y);                             %# Number of samples in y
numFrames = floor(numSamples/frameWidth);           %# Number of full frames in y
energy = zeros(1,numFrames);                        %# Initialize energy
startSample = zeros(1,numFrames);                   %# Initialize start indices
endSample = zeros(1,numFrames);                     %# Initialize end indices

for frame = 1:numFrames                             %# Loop over frames
  startSample(frame) = (frame-1)*frameWidth+1;      %# Starting index of frame
  endSample(frame) = frame*frameWidth;              %# Ending index of frame
  frameIndex = startSample(frame):endSample(frame); %# Indices of frame samples
  energy(frame) = sum(y(frameIndex).^2);            %# Calculate frame energy
end                                                 %# End loop

XX = filtfilt(ones(1,10)/10, 1, energy);            %# Smooths signal

[r,lags] = xcorr(XX,XX,'biased');                   %# Auto-correlates the data
plot(lags,r), xlabel('lag'), ylabel('xcorr')        %# Plots data
```

Comment: What are the units on that graph? An autocorrelation gives the correlation of a single set with itself, with the second set offset by some number of sample (or "frames"). Your graph (I think) shows the correlation (y-axis) as a function of this offset amount (x-axis), so that second peak does not correspond to a single frame.

Comment: Sounds like you are not interpreting the autocorrelation correctly. It gives you an average of how correlated the signal is, with itself, at time lags tau. So as pointed out above, all pairs of data [t_i, t_i-tau] contribute equally to the final autocorr for a given tau. Maybe you are asking how to find the lag value tau that corresponds to the peak you indicate?

Comment: @MusiGenesis the 'data' contains what is shown in this picture: http://a.imageshack.us/img571/5967/waveform.jpg - I had assumed that the Y axis was the correlation, and the x-axis was the frame number, where '2' was the point of zero-lag...

Comment: @Matt Mizumi Yes, in that case, the lag value would be perfect as I would be able to convert that to a frame number.

Comment: @Mark Spivey: could you also upload the 'Three.wav' file from above. You can use something like http://www.multiupload.com/ to host the file..

Comment: @Amro It's just a Wav of Kylie Minogue's - All The Lovers, which is the third song out of a set of 50 that I need to analyse. http://www.mediafire.com/?jbqkd0iecm4dcth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**:

```
%# load the signal
[y, fs, nb] = wavread('Three.wav');
y = mean(y,2);                               %# stereo, take avrg of 2 channels

%# Calculate frame energy
fWidth = round(fs*10e-3);                    %# 10ms
numFrames = floor(length(y)/fWidth);
energy = zeros(1,numFrames);
for f=1:numFrames
  energy(f) = sum( y((f-1)*fWidth+1:f*fWidth).^2 );
end

%# smooth the signal (moving average with window size = 1% * length of data)
WINDOW_SIZE = round(length(energy) * 0.01);  %# 200
XX = filtfilt(ones(1,WINDOW_SIZE)/WINDOW_SIZE, 1, energy);

%# auto-correlation
[r,lags] = xcorr(XX, 'biased');

%# find extrema points
dr = diff(r);
eIdx = find(dr(1:end-1) .* dr(2:end) <= 0) + 1;

[~,loc] = sort(r(eIdx), 'descend');
loc = loc(1:min(3,end));                     %# take the highest 3 values

%# plot
plot(lags,r), hold on
plot(lags(eIdx), r(eIdx), 'g*')
plot(lags(eIdx(loc)), r(eIdx(loc)), 'ro')
hold off, xlabel('lag'), ylabel('xcorr')
```

[image]

and the lag values corresponding to the marked peaks:

```
>> lags( eIdx(loc) )
ans =
           0       -6316        6316
```

Note that we smoothed the signal prior to computing the derivative of the autocorrelation function in order to find the [extrema points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima)

Comment: That's similar to what I want, which is good, but of course with your signal, you are looking at a single peak. As I mentioned in my initial post, I'm struggling to identify the values around the second peak to the right - I just don't know the formula!

Comment: @Mark Spivey: if you increase the moving average window size to say 200 (ie increase the effect of smoothing) `XX = filtfilt(ones(1,200)/200, 1, energy)`, then simply run the same code I posted above and the peaks will be correctly marked: http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/274/greenshot20100817103530.png

Comment: Why does the y axis on your plot have a max xcorr value of 1, whereas mine goes up in increments of 500? That's not right surely?

Comment: Also I get weird 'loc' data, e.g. 12, 16, 8. So I think i'm doing something wrong again..

Comment: @Mark Spivey: I updated the code to use your actual signal. In the previous screenshot, I used the normalized auto-correlation with a range of [0,1]). Note that `loc` indexes `eIdx` which contains the extrema points indices inside the `lag` vector

Comment: @Amro Thank you so much, I now have a working prototype of my thumbnailing system! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Amro How would I go about modifying the lag of the autocorellation? I'm trying to find the chorus section of these songs so I want to see what lag value is the most effective in doing this. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Spivey: the autocorrelation is estimated at each possible lag, so Im not sure what you mean by modifying the lag ??

Comment: @Amro Sorry I meant to say cross-correlation.

Comment: @Amro Never mind that question, it was a stupid thing to ask. I do however have some more sensible questions for you if that's ok? I went through my list of 50 songs. 29 worked, 21 failed to produce a thumbnail. The ones that failed had a very flat slope, so I assumed that the peak picker was struggling to get hold of usable values? Is the likely problem the initial framewidth of the energy samples? I tried adjusting the smoothing strength but it got to a point where it would work, but it would only pick a sample from the first ten seconds - defeating the object of correlation.

Comment: @Mark Spivey: That's definitely one of the difficulties of doing such automated signal processing, its hard to get values that work well for all your input data..

Comment: @Amro Is there anything I could adjust in that extrema point command possibly?

Comment: @Amro Say instead of finding the peak, it could find a period where the decline noticeably flattens out? e.g. http://a.imageshack.us/img340/7407/flato.jpg

Answer (score 1):

1. Smooth the data using a lowpass filter (or average each sample with a number of surrounding samples).
2. Find the peak in the center by looking for the highest sample value.
3. find the valley to the right of the peak by searching for the first sample that has a higher value than its predecessor.
4. Find the peak to the right of the valley by searching for the first sample to a smaller value than its predecessor.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a certain command I could use, rather than making a low pass filter. As you can probably tell, I'm not that technically proficient using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the signal processing toolbox, I think the findpeaks function should do the job for you.

Something like:

```
th = x //(some value that will overlook noise in the data. See the documentation)
[peaks locs] = findpeaks(a,'threshold',th)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/findpeaks.html

I'm used to using it on image intensity data, which doesn't have quite as much local variance as your data (Those "thick" looking sections of your plot are just many data points going up and down quickly, right?). You might need to smooth the data out a bit first to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, currently findpeaks doesn't want to output anything whatsoever.

Comment: Even when you use it without the threshold option? What error/warning does findpeaks return? What format is the data that xcorr returns? Findpeaks only works on Nx1 or 1xN vectors.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried various different options but it just returns a blank matrix. On certain commands it says there are too many output arguments. xcorr returns a 1x40081 double.

Comment: Could you update your question with examples of what you've tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you should use the second output argument of `xcorr` to get your units on the plot correct:

```
Fs = length(data)./T; % or replace with whatever your sample frequency is (44.1 kHz?)
[a,lags] = xcorr(data,data,'biased');
plot(lags./Fs,a);
```

Now you can use your favorite method to get the lag for the second peak; the data explorer button in the figure will do if you just need to do it once. If you need to do it repeatedly, I don't see any way to avoid getting into `findpeaks` or similar.

Comment: I need to use it repeatedly as I want to use it as a batch script in the future. I'm still struggling to use findpeaks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use findpeaks twice. First to get an initial estimate of the peaks and use that results to fine tune the input parameters of the second call to findpeaks. From the question it seems that you want to calculate the pitch value. 
Here is the code :

```
maxlag = fs/50;
r = xcorr(x, maxlag, 'coeff');
r_slice = r(ceil(length(r)/2) : length(r));
[pksh,lcsh] = findpeaks(r_slice);

if length(lcsh) > 1
short = mean(diff(lcsh));
else
    short = lcsh(1)-1;
end

[pklg,lclg] = findpeaks(r_slice,'MinPeakDistance',ceil(short),'MinPeakheight',0.3);

if length(lclg) > 1
    long = mean(diff(lclg));
else
    if length(lclg) > 0
        long = lclg(1)-1;
    else
        long = -1;
    end
end

if long > 0
    pitch = fs / long; % fs is sample rate in Hertz
```

The above is a modified version of the code given [here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/Pitch.html#v44c5761).